# Has the psychological impact of social media exposure for astronauts aboard ISS been studied?

Tags: iss, psychology

Given the "recent" (few years) exposure and access of astronauts/cosmonauts aboard ISS to social media in order to communicate with the general public, I was wondering if the decision to allow them to do so was aided by any psychological assessment. Probably on the positive impact of allowing them more open communication and also feel the support of the people on Earth.

Are there ongoing studies on this, and could there be any negative psychological aspects on this as well?

Comment: I put in a request here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311338241_What_makes_you_tick_The_psychology_of_social_media_engagement_in_space_science_communication. We'll see if it is helpful. A forewarning, a section of this [2017 NASA paper](https://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/trs/_techrep/TM-2017-219286.pdf) suggests that social media is a relatively unaddressed area of astronaut psychology.

Comment: Do you mean a request to get the full text? It would be very interesting to see what it says, indeed. Please if you do get it maybe you can add an answer here, it might even be that this aspect is not yet studied at all, as you mentioned referencing the NASA paper.

Comment: Yes, I requested the full text. I'll definitely post an answer if I get access.

Comment: Unfortunately, the paper didn't really cover astronaut psychology at all. It was about how engaging space science communications were to the public.